# Открытие двух окон в Excel одновременно

Tags: vba, окно, excel, макросы

Возможно ли как-то сделать, чтоб при открытии книги открывалось сразу два окна с определенными листами? (Возможно ли сделать, чтоб открывалось окно на 1\3 рабочей области) мб VBA, макросы как-то помогут?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В *Excel* можно открыть два листа в разных окнах.

После открытия книги (описано для *Excel-2010*):

Вкладка на ленте *Вид-Новое_окно*(нажать), нажать *Восстановить_окно* (в правом верхнем углу, возле кнопок *Закрыть*), после этого задать требуемый размер окон, их расположение,  выбрать нужные листы.

Все это можно проделать **автоматически**.

---

*P.S.* Хитрый "постскриптум" - вынесен выше текста, к которому данное примечание, т.к. решение, показанное здесь, лучше макроса, показанного ранее.

Макрос предложил *ikki*:

В модуль *ЭтаКнига* вставить код, который сработает после активации книги:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    If Me.Windows.Count = 1 Then
        Me.Windows(1).NewWindow
    Else
        Me.Windows(1).Visible = True
        Me.Windows(2).Visible = True
    End If

    Me.Windows(1).WindowState = xlNormal
    Me.Windows(Me.Name & ":1").Activate
    Me.Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlVertical
End Sub
```

Чем решение лучше предыдущего: не нужно задавать размеры окон, достаточно указать расположение окон (в данном случае - указав константу *xlVertical*)

Если же есть желание задать размеры окон в коде, то см. код ниже.

---

В модуль *ЭтаКнига* вставить код, который сработает после активации книги:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Worksheets("Лист1").Activate
    With ActiveWindow
        .WindowState = xlNormal
        .Top = 4
        .Left = 4
        .Width = 510
        .Height = 400
        .NewWindow
        Worksheets("Лист2").Activate
'        .Top = 4
        .Left = 500
'        .Width = 510
'        .Height = 400
    End With

End Sub
```

Выбирается один из листов *Worksheets("имя_листа1")*, задаются размеры окна (*Width, Height*) и его положение (*Top, Left*), активируется второй лист, выбирается положение этого окна (*Left*). Параметры *Width, Height, Top* для второго окна закомментированы. Если нужно задать параметры, отличные от параметров первого окна, строки нужно раскомментировать (убрать апостроф) и вписать нужные числа.

Окна созданы, но возможен вариант, при котором после открытия книги окна развернуты (видимо только одно). Например, такое может быть при наличии другого кода, который разворачивает окно на весь экран (может быть прописан не в данной книге, а в личной книге макросов).

Для отображения созданных окон:

- в общий модуль ставить код

  Sub two_window()

  ```
  ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal
  ```

  End Sub
- на листе разместить какой-либо элемент управления, объект(можно вкладка *Вставка-Фигуры*, выбрать объект), правый клик на объекте, *Назначить_макрос*(выбрать название макроса, здесь *two_window*)-ОК.

Все. После открытия книги нужно нажать кнопку - два окна открыты, можно работать.

При желании кнопку можно разместить на ленте.

Где должны быть размещены макросы, можно прочитать в теме

[Как автоматически при открытии книги запустить макрос в excel?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/139664/vba-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B2-excel)