# Как автоматически при открытии книги запустить макрос в excel?

Tags: vba, excel

Как автоматически при открытии книги запустить макрос в excel?

Comment: [Как автоматически при открытии книги запустить макрос в excel?][1]


  [1]: http://www.google.com/search?q=Как+автоматически+при+открытии+книги+запустить+макрос+в+excel%3F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вставляете это в код:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
'Вместо EntryPoint вставьте название Вашего главного метода'
    Call EntryPoint  
End Sub
```

Правда это не сработает в том случае, если у пользователя в настройках включена блокировка макросов (это включено по умолчанию). Нужно еще помочь ему отключить эту опцию. На самом деле более интересный вопроса как это сделать простым программным методом. Ума не приложу. Наверное через реестр или может есть какая-то встроенная VBA функция для этого.

Код для автозагрузки при открытии Word:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
'Вместо EntryPoint вставьте название Вашего главного метода'
     Call EntryPoint 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Добавлю к ответу *igumnov*.

Код необходимо вставить в модуль *ЭтаКнига* (Для Word - *ThisDocument*)

*Alt+F11* - открываем проект VBA.
Слева - окно проекта, модуль находится там, в папке *Microsoft Excel Objects*

Исполняемый макрос записывается в общий модуль (в папке *Modules*).

Если модуля нет, его нужно создать: в редакторе *VBA* вкладка *Insert-Module*

Если окна проекта нет, открыть - меню *Viev-Project Explorer (Ctrl+R)*

Если макросы запрещены, никакими внутренними встроенными средствами поменять уровень безопасности нельзя. В VBA тоже нет такой команды. Это противоречило бы логике защиты: запрещаем макросы, но тем же макросом их разрешаем.

Поменять уровень безопасности вручную:

Для *Excel-2003*: меню *Сервис-Макрос-Безопасность*

Для *Excel-2010* глубже: закладка ленты *Файл-Параметры-Центр_управления_безопасностью-Параметры_центра_управления_безопасностью-Параметры_макросов*

Программно менять уровень безопасности можно, но перед этим нужно установить на компьютер скрипт, который "умеет" менять уровень безопасности. Такие программы есть в свободном доступе.